Extra characters block validation when going from Xcode to Apple AppStore / TestFlight
I have been attempting to push a ReactNative app to TestFlight, but have been consistently hitting issues in which blank spaces are being inserted into paths by something in the dependencies I've been using.  The characters are blocking validation, thus making me unable to distribute my code to TestFlight.
The two errors that Xcode gives me are:
a) Asset validation failed.  Your package contains a file, '<myappname>/main.jsbundle /Users/<myname>/Library/Developer' with a name that contains invalid characters.  Avoid using control characters in the file names.
b) Asset validation failed.  Your package contains a file '<myappname>/main.jsbundle ' with a name that contains invalid characters.  Avoid using control characters in the name.
Notice that (1) the URL in the first error has a space between main.jsbundle and /Users/...
And that there is a space after main.jsbundle in the second.
From what I can tell, CpResource is supposed to create (or move?) main.jsbundle from my Xcode library into my app when I build the app; and that might be what is creating the space; but we can't identify whether that is true (because we can't find where it is creating the space), and we haven't figured out whether there is another issue that could be causing the problem.
This is not the first build of this app.  Another developer (who was contract and no longer reachable) was able to get 3 previous builds of the app to TestFlight.  But it is the first build that is coming from my Mac.
Thanks for any guidance you can give me -- I've had a dozen attempts blocked due to this validation issue and looking to get passed it.
I have changed the target to ensure that it targets iOS13
I have added code to Podfile to remove references that might cause the problem.
I have manually copied main.jsbundle to my app from my library
I have added app.jsbundle to my app in the same directory
I have removed the test targets (and attempted both without them, and after re-creating them)
I have run pod install several times to see if that fixes the issue
None of these have gotten past this validation issue, although a few of these fixes created other validation issues which I was apparently able to address.
My build of the app runs fine in the simulator.  It's only validation to go to TestFlight that is an issue currently.
CocoaPods installed (version 1.15.2)
Node.js: 20.18.0
React Native: 0.72.10
Yarn: 1.22.22
